# Slow download speed in terminal

Tags: networking, wireless

The download speed in terminal is very slow. (9-15 kb). But the speed in browser works fine. I am using shared internet through my hotspot from mobile. The ubuntu version 19.04

Comment: Can you paste the output of `tracepath 1.1.1.1`?